# Making a F > Celsius converter with gui (tkinter)

Tags: python, string, tkinter

im trying to build an easy GUI with Tkinter and the function should be to convert from Fahrenheit to Celsius. I'm really trying to find out whats wrong down under but I keep getting a fault at "could not convert string to float" at line 31.

```
  File "test.py", line 31, in count
    fahrenheit = float(inputEntry.get()) # Hämtar input angivet av användaren.
ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

Any ideas?

Here is my code so far:

```
#- coding: UTF-8 -*-

import Tkinter
import tkMessageBox

main_window = Tkinter.Tk()
top_frame = Tkinter.Frame(main_window) #i parantes, skriver var framen ska vara
bottom_frame = Tkinter.Frame(main_window) #i parantes, dvs bottom_frame ska va inne i main_window
inputLabel = Tkinter.Label(main_window, text='Skriv antal grader =>', font=('helvetica', 14))
inputEntry = Tkinter.Entry(main_window, width = 5, bg='white', font=('helvetica', 14))
infoLabel = Tkinter.Label(main_window, height = 5, width=40, text='Välkommen till Temperaturomvandlaren!\n' \
                                                            'Nedan kan du omvandla \nFahrenheit till Celsius.', font=('helvetica', 14), bg='#00CC33', fg='white')

def main():
    setupWindow()
    count()
    Tkinter.mainloop()

def setupWindow():
    main_window.title('Temperaturkonverteraren')
    main_window.geometry('380x300+500+250')
    infoLabel = Tkinter.Label(top_frame, text="Här berättas värdet")
    Tkinter.Button(main_window, width = 8, text = "Konvertera", font=('helvetica', 10), bg = "grey",command = count).grid(row=3, column=6, pady=12)
    top_frame.pack()
    bottom_frame.pack()
    infoLabel.pack()
    inputEntry.pack()


def count():
    fahrenheit = float(inputEntry.get()) # Hämtar input angivet av användaren.
    celsius = (fahrenheit - 32) * 5 / 9
    if celsius > 0: # Metod för hantering av färg och värden.
        infoLabel.configure(bg='#CC0000', text='Det blir %.2f grader Celsius.' % (celsius,))
    elif celsius  < 0:
        infoLabel.configure(bg='#3366CC', text='Det blir %.2f grader Celsius.' % (celsius,))
    else:
        infoLabel.configure(bg='#00CC33', text='Det blir %.2f grader Celsius.' % (celsius,))


if __name__ == '__main__': 
    main()
```

Comment: Presumably line 31 is `celsius = (fahrenheit - 32) ...`? IF not, then you really should indicate WHERE line 31 is, because we're not very good at counting.

Comment: Copied to my editor; the line is `fahrenheit = float(...` Is the error really in converting `float` to `str`, or rather `str` to `float`? Tested... it is `could not convert string to float`. Edited to include the correct error.

Comment: @Dolcens Do you mean `cannot convert string to float`?

Comment: @MarcB sorry. Yes, that is line 31. This line says could not convert string to float: 
    fahrenheit = float(inputEntry.get())

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are calling `fahrenheit = float(inputEntry.get())` without a value in the entry. In `main` you initialize the GUI but right after you call count and of course the entry sill not have a value! You should change your code and call count just after the user actually input something in `inputEntry` and possible verify the value of the user before trying to convert it to float.

you can do something like this:

```
val = inputEntry.get()
if not val:
    val = 0.0
fahrenheit = float(val)
```

This is a very basic check because the user could input something like `'10F'` and that cannot be converted to float.

Comment: Or use a `try/except` block. However, this solves only part of the problem. When I try, the GUI won't show at all.

Comment: Yes that would be a better approach. And yes it seems like are other problems in the code.